# Trouble with Collision in Java (with Rectangles)

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, rectangles

I'm having trouble getting collision between Rectangles in Java.

I'm pretty new to programming, and this is my first "serious" project (it's a recreation of pong lol) but anyway, here's my method so far:

```
public static void Collision(){

    if(ballArea().intersects(Background.gameTop())){
        isGoingUp = false;
        System.out.println("hit");
    } else if(ballArea().intersects(Background.gameBottom())){
        isGoingUp = true;
        System.out.println("hit");
    } else if(ballArea().intersects(Background.gameRight())){
        isGoingRight = false;
        System.out.println("hit");
    } else if(ballArea().intersects(Background.gameLeft())){
        isGoingUp = true;
        System.out.println("hit");
    } 
}

public static Rectangle ballArea(){

    return new Rectangle(ballXPos, ballYPos, ballXSize, ballYSize);
}
```

I have Rectangles for the sides of the screen so far, but I'm having trouble getting the collision to work. Thanks for the help. :)

// edit, I can post more if you need more

Comment: There's nothing funny about Pong!

Comment: Of course. I just found it silly that I'm calling Pong my first "serious" project.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

There was a simple error in the positioning for the Rectangles, and I had one variable wrong in an if statement. Still learning though! =D